# Castling rule clarification

Tags: rules, castling

A quote from Wikipedia for castling rule:

> the squares between the king and the rook involved are unoccupied

What if the squares are not occupied at this instance but an opponent piece was there before?

I tried on a computer chess game, it would not allow a castling move.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

FIDE Article 3.8:

> (1) The right to castle has been lost:
>
> - if the king has already moved, or
> - with a rook that has already moved.
>
> (2) Castling is prevented temporarily:
>
> - if the square on which the king stands, or the square which it must
>     cross, or the square which it is to occupy, is attacked by one or more
>     of the opponent's pieces, or
> - if there is any piece between the king and the rook with which
>     castling is to be effected.

The fact that a enemy piece previously occupied a square between the king and rook does not make castling illegal. Instead, there is probably some other reason why castling is not permitted.

Comment: My guess is that one of the squares between the king and rook was attacked.

Comment: You were right.  I over looked one of the square.

Comment: Viewed 6 times and already accepted.